# Suggestions for IDE with code auto-completion for web development (LAMP) in Ubuntu

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ubuntu

I am looking for an editor (IDE) for developing PHP web applications. I would need it to handle HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP at the minimum.

What I am looking for is code auto-completion functionality within the software. Like for example, as I type `mysql_c`, it should bring up `mysql_connect()` with the arguments and syntax.

I come from Windows background and I was using codelobster php for programming. It was just perfect until I switched over to Linux (Ubuntu 12.04), only to find that it is not available in Linux.

Please suggest similar IDEs that support autocompletion.

Comment: This is a very general question. Simple search for 'PHP IDE' at stackoverflow will throw a lot of records

Comment: Pedantic comment: when typing `mysql_c` you're better of with an IDE that discourages you to carry on, or use `PDO` instead

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - that was really 'pedantic' :)

Comment: @kallakafar - sorry for that, but there is some truth to it. Suppose you set up your app on a server with `E_ALL` on, your content is bound to get buried under warnings saying you're using deprecated functions, if you ignore them long enough you'll find that the latest version of php doesn't support your code anymore. Better be pedantic and safe then a sorry creature of habit. (to put it bluntly) BTW: I have used PhpDesigner in the past for web dev, it's not too shabby, but not free. Eclipse is not too bad either, but give netbeans a try, too

Answer (score 2):

For those requirements, I'd recommend JetBrains' [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). I've used it and other JetBrains IDEs built on the same platform for many years and have been very happy with them. It's not free, however.

Answer (score 1):

Any decent IDE would support that, besides this question is already asked before.

So, according to your requierments, I can recommend:

1.[Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt) - Really good, I'm currently using it with XDebug.
2.[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/)    - It was my favorite till I failed to install a Debugger on it. then switched to PDT

these two IDE's provides code completion, syntax checking, and integration with debuggers.
Also, both of them are cross-platform, which means if you ever wanted to return to Windows, they'll be there  for you.

Still not intrested? 
[take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20ide)

Comment: Netbeans has a working xdebug plugin…

Comment: @feeela I know that, that's why I said `I failed`. Because it just didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) for a while now & I feel it is the best for web development.

With a lot of active packages/plugins it makes redundant tasks much easier.

And so far it has never crashed, unlike eclipse which hangs/crashes after a while. You should definitely give it a try.